# Partial Least Squares Regression : deflation of the Y matrix

Tags: regression, algorithms, latent-variable, partial-least-squares

I am digging deep into the PLSR algorithms and while I have found multiple flavours of if (different normalisations, SIMPLS,..), there is always something in the Y deflation that is throwing me off for things akin to PLS2.
First of all, here are some algorithms!

[image: Partila Least Squares algorithm]

Let us now look at the one of the right by Höskuldsson. 
More specifically I am interested in *Step 6*. 
Why is the deflation like that? 
I understand that one wants to use the *th* score to deflate (predictive purpose) but I'm confused on why one would use *ch'*.
Along the lines of **Step 5** (which makes a lot of sense to make me), why not deflate with the following for **Step 6**:

[image: deflation_equation]

I saw both algorithms frequently, but I can't understand why the outer relation for  *Y* in PLSR is *UC'* and not *UQ'*, whereas for *X* it's *TP'* and not *TW'*. 
Is anyone aware of why the implementations are like that?

Comment: Where is the figure from?

Comment: I got lazy with the references, I apologize. 
Link : https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/wics.1239 
Paper in case link dies  : Partial least squares algorithms and methods, Vincenzo Esposito Vinzi and Giorgio Russolillo, WIREs Comput Stat 2013, 5:1–19. doi: 10.1002/wics.1239

Comment: Thanks. The clearest explanation/overview of different PLS flavours that I know of is http://www.ofai.at/~roman.rosipal/Papers/pls_book06.pdf. Did you check what deflating schemes it describes in Section 2.1 and what these two methods quoted in your post correspond to?

Comment: I know of this paper as well ! Both methods in my post correspond to what is called PLS2. The second one normalizes ch, while the first one does not, which makes the deflation steps look different. But they're equivalent in fact! The beta coefficient is just equal to 1 in the first method and thus ommited). 

What I was thinking of is sort of akin to the deflation step of "canonical" PLS or PLS Mode A in your paper. The notation is the same as well. In the notations of Rosipal I was thinking of this to do "regression" PLS: 

Y = Y - Beta(u|t) * t * q^T. Why would one use c^T and not q^T?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused now. Are you saying that the two algorithms listed in your question are equivalent? I thought your whole question was about their differences! I did not understand the second part of your comment either...

Comment: Yes, both algorithms give the same results. My question isn't about the differences, but rather on why the Y-deflation is done with c^T and not with q^T for those algorithms (i.e. PLS2 basically) ! You can clearly see in Step 5 that X-loadings are used to deflate, while Step 6 actually uses Y- weights ! Y loadings would be what is called q^T ! Did I formulate it better this time?

Comment: I think you are saying that "PLS Mode A" makes more sense to you than PLS2 and are asking what is the point of PLS2 at all. Right? PLS Mode A deflates Y using q, so seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: But what I would like to know is why you would deflate using c^T and not q^T ? 
"PLS Mode A" is "canonical" PLS where the relationship betwen Y and X is symetrical. I am questioning why this doesn't just translate with Y = Y - Beta(u|t) * t * q^T for PLS2 or "regression" PLS, and people used Y = Y - Beta(u|t) * t * c^T instead ! I mean for the X deflation one uses X-loadings as well. So why not for Y-deflation when doing regression mode. I want to know if there is any justification behind it  !

Comment: Wait -- the formula in Rosipal for deflating in PLS2 is Y - tc', there is no beta term that you wrote in the last comment.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I don't understand the logic behind your specific proposal... The PLS2 deflation Y = Y-tc' I understand very well, here t is interpreted as the predictor and c is computed by regressing Y on this predictor. So Y-tc' just subtracts from Y everything that can be explained by t. In other words, it replaces Y with the residuals after regressing t out. It is very logical thing to do in the "regression" context. I could write this as an answer, but I am not sure if you already understand that and are asking about something else!

Comment: I think there are some typos in the algorithm. Regardless, the idea behind deflation is reconstructing both X and Y for specifically that component by t*p' (for X) and by t*c' (for Y) followed by their removal as @amoeba stated. Since u is the scores of Y and q relates "that u score" to Y and not t to Y, it is pretty much useless. Its being useless is also stated in the article you refered. "Hoskuldsson’s algorithm is presented in the
right part of Algorithm 1; in Step 3, Y-loadings
qh are obtained. The calculation of qh has no
algorithmic relevance, but it highlights ...."